# Non finitely presented subgroup

Tags: group-theory

Consider the kernel of the homomorphism from two copies of the free group 
$F_2 \times F_2$ onto the integers sending every generator to 1. How to see that this subgroup is not finitely presented?

Comment: Sorry, what's $F_2$? Surely not the field of two elements?

Comment: Surely the free group of rank 2.

Comment: This looks related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/54975/when-is-a-finitely-generated-group-finitely-presented/54982#54982

Comment: Ah, I mis-parsed it. It's not, "two copies of (the free group $F_2\times F_2$)," it's that $F_2\times F_2$ is two copies of the free group $F_2$. So, what are the generators of $F_2\times F_2$?

Answer (score 7):

This is actually a standard example of a finitely generated but not finitely presented group. I seem to remember that there is a homological proof. I have been trying to think of a reasonably straightforward group-theoretical proof, but I am running out of time.

What I have done is to calculate an (infinite) presentation of the kernel $K$ in question. Let the two copies of $F_2$ be generated by $\{a,b\}$ and $\{x,y\}$. Then $K$ is generated by $B := ba^{-1}$, $X := xa^{-1}$ and $Y := ya^{-1}$. Using a reasonably straightforward Reidemeister-Schreier calculation, we get the presentation

$\langle\, X, Y, B \mid [B,(YX^{-1})^{X^i}]\:  (i \in \mathbb{Z})\, \rangle$

of $K$, which is an HNN-extension of the free group $\langle X,Y \rangle$ with stable letter $B$, where the subgroup generated by $(YX^{-1})^{X^i}$ for $i \in \mathbb{Z}$, which is not finitely generated, is centralized by $B$.

Edited: To show that $K$ is not finitely presentable, it is enough to show that any group $K'$ defined by a presentation using a finite subset of the relators in the above presentation is unequal to $K$. Notice that $K'$ is also an HNN-extension of $\langle X,Y \rangle$ by $B$, but the subgroup of $\langle X,Y \rangle$ centralized by $B$ is finitely generated, and so is a proper subgroup of the subgroup centralized by $B$ in $K$. So $K \ne K'$ and hence $K$ is not finitely presentable.

Comment: "To show that K is not finitely presentable, it is enough to show that any group K′ defined by a presentation using a finite subset of the relators in the above presentation is unequal to K." This is not obvious to me.

Comment: Ths is basically a lemma of B. Neumann: If a group is finitely presented, then given any presentation with infinitely many relators one can remove all but finitely many relators to obtain a finite presentation of the same group.

Comment: You could just apply asphericity instead of the last paragraph - presentations of HNN extensions with free associated subgroups are aspherical, and hence minimal.

Comment: @MustafaGokhanBenli Do you have a reference for that lemma? I've been searching for a while and I'm empty handed!

Comment: QPrototank This could be a nice exercise. AS a reference, see Baumslag's book (Topics in Combinatorial Group Theory) Theorem 12 on Page 52.

Answer (score 5):

Euler characteristics of classifying spaces give a way to see this.  The Euler characteristic of the free group $F_2$ is -1, because the figure of 8 
has two 1-cells and one 0-cell.  Euler characteristics multiply for direct products, so the Euler characteristic of $F_2 \times F_2$ is 1.  The Euler characteristic of the infinite cyclic group is 0 (= the Euler characteristic of the circle).

In general, if $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ with quotient $Q=G/N$, there is a product formula: the Euler characteristic of $G$ is the product of those of $N$ and $Q$, whenever all three Euler characteristics are defined.

Going back to our example, since there is no solution to $1=0.x$, we see that the kernel cannot have an Euler characteristic.  We know that the kernel is finitely generated, and we know that it has a 2-dimensional classifying space, so the only way it can fail to have an Euler characteristic is if the classifying space needs infinitely many 2-cells, or equivalently if the kernel is not finitely presented.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Thanks - it hadn't occurred to me to use MathJax.