# Calculating $\chi(\mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})$, the Euler characteristic?

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, geometric-group-theory

Question 1:

> For a discrete group $G$, does $\chi(G)$ denote the Euler characteristic of $G$, or is this notation commonly used for something else?

For the next three questions, assume $\chi$ does denote Euler characteristic. (I am asking to check on some references.)

Question 2:

> Is it the case that if $G$ is a finite group, then $\chi(G) = 1/|G|$?

An affirmative answer to question 2 is stated at the bottom of the generalizations section [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_characteristic).

Question 3:

> Suppose $G$ and $H$ are groups such that $\chi(G)$ and $\chi(H)$ exist, does $\chi(G * H) = \chi(G) + \chi(H) - 1$?

If it is the case that $\chi(G)$ exists implies that $G$ has a finite classifying space, then an affirmative answer to question 3 is given on page 46 [here](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/b4e7/112c5b12222ac46c616dc5a3b8f968998753.pdf).

Question 4:

> Is $\chi(\mathbb{Z}) = 0$?

This is stated [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35579/non-finitely-presented-subgroup), and I think can be seen since the circle $S^1$ is the classifying space of the infinite cyclic group, and the circle consists of one 0-cell and one 1-cell, and 0 = 1 - 1.

Of course, if the answers to all the above questions are yes, then we would have that 
$$
\begin{aligned}
\chi(\mathbb{Z} * \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}) 
&= \chi(\mathbb{Z}) + \chi( \mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}) - 1\\
&= 0 + \frac{1}{m} - 1\\
&= \frac{1}{m} - 1.
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Without any other context, I'd assume that $\chi(G)$ denotes the Euler characteristic of $K(G, 1)$ if $G$ is torsion-free (and f.g., and probably a few other mild constraints). If $G$ is just virtually torsion-free, take $\chi(G) =  \chi(H) / [G:H]$ for $H\subset G$ torsion-free and of finite index. That gives, for example, the relation $\chi(G) = 1/\#G$ for $G$ finite. Question (3) should hold with some reasonable conditions on $G$ and $H$, and (4) follows from the fact that $K(\mathbb{Z}, 1) = S^1$.

Comment: See [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1511.09436.pdf) for Question 3 and 4. Take $H=1$ the trivial group in $A\ast_H B$.

Comment: If I remember correctly (I'm away from my bookshelves at the moment), this construction is covered in Brown's "Cohomology of Groups." There's probably something in Serre's "Trees" as well.

Comment: @anomaly Thank you for your comments. (I'll have to check out Brown's book.) And I am only interested in the case that $G$ is a f.g. group.

Comment: @DietrichBurde, Thank you for the reference, but it appears that an answer of yes to question 3 is literally one of the assumptions of Tsouvalas' Theorem 3.5. (And it appears that you're using the conclusion (ii) of that theorem to then get that the answer to question 3 is yes.)

Comment: You probably need to assume that $G$ has finite cohomological dimension over $\mathbf{Q}$ to make this Euler characteristic well-defined. This is not just a mild assumption: it fails for many finitely generated torsion-free groups. However it holds for the groups in consideration.