# Finitely presented group with all rank $2$ subgroups not finitely presented?

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

Is there a finitely presented group $G$ where every noncyclic subgroup $H$ of $G$ that is generated by $2$ elements is not finitely presented?

Context:

I was wondering about subgroups of finitely presented groups - I know that they need not be finitely generated (for example, the kernel of the abelianization $F_2 \to \mathbb{Z}^2$) and even when they are finitely generated, they need not be finitely presented (for example,
the kernel of $F_2 \times F_2 \to \mathbb{Z}$ sending all the obvious generators to $1$ - see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35579/non-finitely-presented-subgroup/35694#35694)).  I was wondering if there is always some finitely presented proper nontrivial subgroup and then I realized, of course cyclic subgroups need to be ruled out.  So then I thought about the above question. Then I realized that I had no idea how to approach it - hence the question.

Comment: Thanks for improving the question! If you don't get an answer in the next couple of days, you could probably post it to MathOverflow.

Comment: I would expect any counter-example to be difficult to construct - there are some serious results which are constructions of groups which contain no two-generated subgroups of a specific kind (Noel Brady, and more recently Yash Lodha, constructed torsion-free finitely presented groups which are not hyperbolic & contain no "Baumslag-Solitar" subgroups - fancier examples appeared on the arXiv last week). A counter-example to your question would also be a counter-example to the question Brady was answering, although his groups do not answer your question (they contain non-abelian free subgroups).

Comment: @user1729 Ahh ok, thanks - do you happen to know the name of the paper by Brady?

Comment: [Here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1403.6716) is the paper of Lodha, which cites Brady's paper. I doubt that their proofs will help you though - they construct finitely presented torsion-free subgroups $H$ of hyperbolic groups which are not themselves hyperbolic. Then $H$ has no Baumag-Solitar subgroup and is not hyperbolic, just like the groups you are after. On the other hand, as $H$ embeds into a hyperbolic group it contains the free group of rank two. So you are trying to construct similar groups but in a completely different way - doing so would be very interesting, but also very hard.

Comment: @user1729 Thanks for link and comments, yeah I now think I'm in way over my head if I'm hoping for an example (and my totally naive guess is that there should be an example).